How to put contact info from Client INFO sheet into Sold Sheet
I'm trying to put contact info from my Client INFO sheet into my Sold Sheet.
It should add to the first blank cell c4 in the Sold Sheet.  Instead it is at c28 and keeps going down every time I press another Accept Cell from Client INFO.
Also when I unpress Accept it should remove the info it pasted but it is not deleted on my Sold Sheet.
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wsClientInfo As Worksheet
    Dim wsSold As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim lastRowTrackingSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowValue As Variant
    Dim srcRange As Range
    Dim destRange As Range
    Dim wsExists As Boolean
    Dim isRow2Empty As Boolean

    Set wsClientInfo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Info") ' Name of the sheet where you're double-clicking
    Set wsSold = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sold") ' Name of the sheet where you want to paste the row

    ' Check if the Tracking sheet exists
    wsExists = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set lastRowTrackingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracking")
    If Not lastRowTrackingSheet Is Nothing Then
        wsExists = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If Tracking sheet does not exist, create it
    If Not wsExists Then
        Set lastRowTrackingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        lastRowTrackingSheet.Name = "Tracking"
        lastRowTrackingSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden ' Hide the sheet
        lastRowTrackingSheet.Range("A1").Value = 2 ' Initialize with row 2
    End If

    ' Retrieve and validate the last used row value from the Tracking sheet
    lastRowValue = lastRowTrackingSheet.Range("A1").Value

    ' Check if the double-clicked cell is in the "Contacted" column
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Toggle between "Contacted" and blank
        If Target.Value = "Contacted" Then
            Target.Value = ""
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Remove the green color
        Else
            Target.Value = "Contacted"
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Set the background color to green
        End If
        Cancel = True ' Prevents cell from entering edit mode

    ' Check if the double-clicked cell is in the "Accepted" column
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Toggle between "Accepted" and blank
        If Target.Value = "Accepted" Then
            Target.Value = ""
        Else
            Target.Value = "Accepted"
        End If

        ' If the value is "Accepted", copy only the specified columns to the "Sold" sheet
        If Target.Value = "Accepted" Then
            ' Ensure that lastRowValue is a number
            If IsNumeric(lastRowValue) Then
                destRow = CLng(lastRowValue) + 1
            Else
                ' If lastRowValue is not numeric, start from row 3
                destRow = 3
            End If

            ' Check if row 2 in the Sold sheet is empty
            isRow2Empty = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsSold.Rows(2)) = 0

            ' Ensure pasting starts at row 3 if row 2 is not empty
            If Not isRow2Empty And destRow <= 2 Then destRow = 3
            
            ' Define the source range (columns C, D, E, F) from the source row
            Set srcRange = wsClientInfo.Range("C" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row)
            
            ' Define the destination range (columns C, D, E, F) in the destination row
            Set destRange = wsSold.Range("C" & destRow & ":F" & destRow)
            
            ' Copy only the specific columns
            destRange.Value = srcRange.Value
            
            ' Update the last used row in the Tracking sheet
            lastRowTrackingSheet.Range("A1").Value = destRow

            ' Optionally clear the row's content in the "Client Info" sheet
            ' Target.EntireRow.ClearContents

            ' Prevents cell from entering edit mode
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub


First you need to create a short simple macro which makes that causes an issue.

Set lastRowTrackingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) You may want to use last row in the specific column you're working.

Regarding the "undo" portion of your problem, I'm not seeing a match/find/search in your code to verify the line to remove.  That would also give some data validation, since you need to save the row number as a variable to go back and remove otherwise.

What is the purpose of copying "Accepted" rows to the other sheet, if they also remain on the original sheet?  You could just add a filter on Column L and keep it all on one sheet.

I don't think you need the "last row" tracking sheet - all it does really is add more complexity.  Without that sheet:
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim wsSold As Worksheet
    Dim NextRow As Long
    
    If Target.Column = 11 Then 'Col K ?
        If Target.Value = "Contacted" Then ' Toggle between "Contacted" and blank
            Target.Value = ""
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Remove the green color
        Else
            Target.Value = "Contacted"
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Set the background color to green
        End If 'Contacted
        Cancel = True ' Prevents cell from entering edit mode

    ElseIf Target.Column = 12 Then 'Col L ?
        ' Toggle between "Accepted" and blank
        Set wsSold = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sold")
        If Target.Value = "Accepted" Then
            Target.Value = ""
            'unclear what you expect here??? How would this row be found
            '  on the "Sold" sheet so it could be removed?
        Else
            Target.Value = "Accepted"
            NextRow = LastOccupiedRow(wsSold) + 1    'next empty row
            If NextRow < 3 Then NextRow = 3          'check at least row3
            ' "C1:F1" is *relative to each row*
            wsSold.Rows(NextRow).Range("C1:F1").Value = Target.EntireRow.Range("C1:F1").Value
        End If 'Accepted
        Cancel = True ' Prevents cell from entering edit mode
    End If
End Sub

'what is the last occupied row on sheet `ws` ?
Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function

